# How to create one to many in mongoDB using java

Tags: java, mongodb, data-structures, database

So I'm trying to make a system that is one of many styles DB in mongo using java.I am trying to recreate a school grading database where there are: teachers, classes, periods, students and their grades attributes. But my question is how do I implement one to many in java, for example, teachers and the classes they teach.

[big diagram of DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfApW.png)

[more precise diagram of DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L335A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this you code have a student as a new doc, the name is an index and grades/assignments are an array with hashmaps within. And have collections made when a teacher tries to access it for the first time.

EXP: If Mr.Rogers has 3 classes, ask him for the classes and create them, such as "Rogers_math_alg_2" etc

Answer (score 1):

I think that the question that you're asking is more about the schema design itself, the fact that it's "in java" seems irrelevant to your question.

Anyhow, it's quite a broad question and a broad topic. There's rarely, if ever, one way to approach a schema design.

I'd suggest you start with broadening your knowledge of the schema design process, and the various tradeoffs of different approaches.

Here are some resources to get you started:

- [6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design: Part 1](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) (links to
  parts 2 and 3 within)
- [Data Model Design (MongoDB docs)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/)

I think that after you've gone through those you should have some ideas around various approaches to your particular model, and you can check back here for additional help if needed. :-)

Comment: So i read that i have a better understanding though im still lost on how to connect with java

Comment: It would be helpful then if you could add more specific information to your question about what you've tried, and where specifically you are stuck. You could start with an outline of your Java object model, e.g. you have a Student class, that contains a List of Grades, etc. etc.

Comment: So I understand I must use sets or some kind of data structure in classes in order to create the relationship though my issue is how do I get those lists and upload those list to the DB . in other word handle the lists in the DB for the relationships. In addition I'm thinking a more of a embedded approach.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class Teacher and annoate with @Document(Collection_name="Teacher") and create List of Classes inside Teacher . Rest Mongo will take care.